# 'Couldn't load PyQGIS' after upgrade to Raring Ringtail?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, update

I upgraded my Ubuntu to Raring Ringtail.

After that, when starting QGIS I receive a message:

```
Couldn't load PyQGIS.
Python support will be disabled.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
RuntimeError: the sip module implements API v9.0 to v9.2 but the qgis.core module requires API v8.1  

Python version:
2.7.4 (default, Apr 19 2013, 18:30:41) 
[GCC 4.7.3]

QGIS version:
1.7.5-Wroclaw 'Wroclaw', exported

Python path:
['/usr/share/qgis/python', '/home/rdk/.qgis/python', '/home/rdk/.qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyspatialite-2.6.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/networkx-1.5-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.4.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twittercollect-0.1.0-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-1.1-py2.7.egg', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Shapely-1.2.14-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

What is causing such problem? How could I fix it?

Comment: Which repos do you use?

Comment: @underdark `ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable` for the moment. But I cannot see `qgis` there for Raring.. Could that be causing installation of 1.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to QGIS 1.8: http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#26-Ubuntu

The problem is your sip is too new to work with the older 1.7 release.

Comment: I tried follow the instruction but when I run `sudo apt-get install qgis` the qgis version that install is the 1.7.5 :(