# Unable to install QGIS 1.8 on Ubuntu

Tags: qgis, installation, ubuntu, linux

Can someone please walk me through installing qgis on Ubuntu 13.04. I keep getting 1.7 no matter what I do and I would like 1.8 if possible. I am a new Linux user.

This was addressed in a previous post but it still did not fix my problem. I was still getting the same errors even when I followed this post: 
[Cannot fix QGIS after upgrade to Ubuntu 13.04 Raring](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60398/cannot-fix-qgis-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-04-raring)

---

I was finally able to figure it out:

On the QGIS website I installed this http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/Download#262-With-updated-dependencies section 2.6.2

I actually had to download these packages from the site:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install qgis
```

Comment: No matter how many times I install and uninstall the program it still downloads 1.7 qgis. I followed the instructions from here: http://northwestspatial.com/wp/?p=328 and another post on stack: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60398/cannot-fix-qgis-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-13-04-raring

Comment: Can you post a significant amount of detail in terms of screenshots, errors, etc, of your issue. So far it seems hard to answer your specific issue without such detail

Comment: Rather than add a few extra details as a comment can you include them as a revision to your original question which you should be able to do using the edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote up my method for installing QGIS on Ubuntu 12.04. That's two releases behind, but installation on your system should be similar. I also installed GDAL, GEOS, and PostGIS from source in previous posts, but those steps are not required to install QGIS.

http://northwestspatial.com/wp/?p=395

Comment: I followed the instructions on the site but I still have qgis 1.7. I went into the software center and deleted qgis then followed your instructions but 1.7 still downloaded.

Comment: I actually had to download this package from the site:sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install qgis